# Why do we use $\Delta m$ in the derivation of angular momentum of a rigid body?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, mass, notation, rigid-body-dynamics

[image]

while I was watching a derivation of angular momentum of a rigid body on youtube, it came to my attention that the person who was doing the derivation, used $\Delta m$. my question is, why did he use delta m? I mean even if a force is applied to a rigid body, mass remains the same. delta means change right? but mass does not change. I've shared a screenshot of the derivation.

Comment: Where in the derivation? You should at least show some of the steps here to make the question a clear.

Comment: m=▲m1+▲m2+....+▲mn (this is how he started the derivation. I dont know how else to explain. I've tried but I dont think we can share pictures. I really need the answer. can I email u or do u want me to share the link to the video I've watched?)

Comment: That does not clarify the problem, and you should be adding it to the question and not in a comment. See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) about how to use _Mathjax_ for equation rendering. You could add a link to the video and the relevant timestamp, but this is not recommended since videos are sometimes moved or deleted. Thanks.

Comment: I've shared the derivation in my question.

Comment: Okay. Also note that we also don't recommend adding images. But the reason there are instances of $\Delta m$ has nothing to do with changing mass, but they are adding together individual elements of mass $\Delta m_i$ at positions $r_i$ to get the total angular momentum $L=\sum L_i$. The sum of all the $\Delta m_i$ gives the total mass of the rigid body and an expression for the angular momentum of the body $L=I_i\omega=\sum_i(\Delta m_i r_i^2)\omega=I\omega$ is obtained.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/550071) for typesetting and see also [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/36194) on the use of screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it doesn't represent a temporal change in mass, but rather the amount of mass in a small section of the body such that $\sum_i\Delta m_i=M$ is the mass of the body.